# Query in managed package

Tags: force.com, managed-package

We are having a requirement wherein our application is being deployed as a Managed Package on a customer's org. We need to access some of the objects in the org's

schema within our Managed Package. However, any references to fields outside the Managed Package is leading to creation of duplicate fields (with namespace of the

Managed Package appended) on deployment of the Managed Package. For example, in one of my classes we are referring to a field 'Role_c'in the account object. When I

deploy the Managed Package, there is another field __Role_c created in the object and this new field is referenced within my class. Is there a way to refer

to fields outside the Managed Package without creating these duplicate fields?

Comment: Read up on Describe Information starting at getGlobalDescribe(). Links: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm and https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_global_describe.htm#apex_dynamic_global_describe